# Why is this right principally injective ring a self-injective ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If $R$ is a semiprime ring, right principally injective and satisfies ACC on right annihilators of elements, is it self-injective?

I only know that it is right nonsingular.

Comment: Quick question: what do you mean by "right principally injective" - right principal ideals are injective ? (surely not ?!) Kind regards - Stephan F. Kroneck.

Comment: Yes,and principally injective means divisible.From Lam:Lectures on modules and rings,p119.

Comment: See if you can use the chain condition to show that $R$ is equal to $Q_{max}^r(R)$, since $R$ already embeds in $Q_{max}^r(R)$. I'd also like to add that I've seen that the ACC on *all* right ideals with $R$ right princ-inj means $R$ is perfect, but I can't seem to find anything with just point annihilators. Another thing is that I hope you didn't switch up sides, because they can be tricky, here.

Comment: Right principally injective rings are those for which a module homomorphism from a principal right ideal into the ring can be extended to the entire ring. Another characterization is that l(r(a))=Ra  for every a∈R , where l  denotes the left annihilator and r  the right annihilator.